# manage virtual machines with virsh

Tags: libvirt

I installed `libvirt` and `virt-manager`, but `virt-manager` isn't working. Is there a good tutorial on using `virsh`. I got the following message when creating a virtual machine in virt-manager:

```
Error launching manager: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_storage_format'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/engine.py", line 889, in _do_show_create
    self._get_create_dialog().show(src.topwin, uri)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 170, in show
    self.reset_state(uri)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 393, in reset_state
    self.addstorage.reset_state()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/addstorage.py", line 196, in reset_state
    fmt = self.conn.get_default_storage_format()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default_storage_format'
```

Comment: what, exactly, do you mean by "virt-manager isn't working"?

Answer (score 0):

A search indicates this may actually be a bug,

[bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/1448631](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virt-manager/+bug/1448631)

There are steps within the bug comments where there is a suggestion of dependencies not being installed:

Looking up packages installed etc, could you provide with:

```
dpkg -l | grep qemu
```

Or your OS equivalent (`rpm` etc) as you haven't specified the flavour.